# What are techniques for textual analysis: distinct topic extraction (unsupervised), unique word clusters?

Tags: text-analysis

Say, I’m writing a non-fiction book on some subject.

The book covers a couple of themes, and each theme consists of chapters with descriptions of topics within that theme. (Not that it matters, but it’s practical philosophical-ish.) For example, there are seven themes and each theme consists of (roughly) eight topics.

With the aim of writing a concise text, I want to minimize the semantic overlap between topics. So, when comparing each topic/chapter with any of the other chapters, I would like to see a high cohesion within each topic and limited overlap between chapters.

Visually, if I'd cluster all the book’s words, I’d expect to see distinct groups with each topic a separate group (after filtering out stop words and other generic words). Or put differently, I would expect to be able to get lists of words that are unique and telling for each topic since they don’t appear in any other topic.

What’s a technique (or even term for this need, other than “textual analysis”) that I could use? Any tool that you’d know? Any other book (!) that you can recommend on this topic?

[English isn't my native language, so apologies for any grammatical errors.]

Comment: What you're discussing sounds like an interesting exercise, but not like a meaningful strategy to improve the coherency or conciseness of your writing.

Comment: You can try a word cloud for each chapter (many free online), but agree with previous comment: this will provide no meaningful analysis other than the prevalence of words within the chapters. Try it and see.

Comment: I'm not sure non-fiction is so different from fiction in this regard, but reading the manuscript, especially after having put it away for some time should give you an idea of if something doesn't work or doesn't make sense. Creating a shorter synopsis or summary of the book and each chapter would make it easier to get an overview and help you see problematic similarities. Unless the book is covering widely different topics, most "dumb" textual analysis will provide little help but rather waste your time...

Comment: @Erk, "Creating a shorter synopsis or summary of the book and each chapter would make it easier to get an overview and help you see problematic similarities." is exactly what I was referring to. Indeed, I can do that manually. I was hoping to have some tool support that with text analysis on words, synonyms, meaning... That concepts in one chapter have limited semantic overlap with concepts in other chapters. Thanks!

Comment: @wetcircuit, it's not just about plain occurrence of literal words, but more about occurrence of concepts across different chapters. I'm looking for a somewhat strict division of topics across chapters, not having too many concepts occur in multiple chapters. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Clarifying my thinking (hopefully): consider a book about cooking, just as an example. Themes might be bread, fish, vegetables, meat, desserts, drinks. Within each theme, there are obviously recipes with different types of ingredients. What I'd like to see is an analysis of whether each theme is sufficiently delineated with limited cross-overs to other themes. So, "flour" occurs heavily in bread, but not (that often) in chapters on fish and meat and drinks. "Beef" occurs only in the chapter on meat. Dairy is mainly in chapter on desserts. "Ice cubes" is mainly in chapter on drinks.

Comment: You're assuming something not yet in evidence. The fallacy: fish and vegetables in a cookbook will not be 'exclusive' in the way you think because cookbooks don't describe bare fish and bare vegetables, these items do not need to be in a cookbook, certainly not full chapters of unseasoned fish. Instead you will find the final dishes which will use standard ingredients used in the sauces, glazes, and composite dishes (flour, sugar, etc). Another metaphor is looking at an instruction book on software and assuming each chapter is siloed rather than building on info that came before. Try and see.

Comment: You're owning different cooking books than I :-) Take a look at the excellent _How to Cook Everything_ (Mark Bittman) or _The Food Lab_ (Kenji Lopez-Alt). They have separate sections for fish, meat, vegetables, pasta and others as the main theme of the recipes in those chapters. Indeed, recipes will combine ingredients obviously, but I guess the main topic of chapters would be deductable from the contents (and such main topics will have limited cross-over into other chapters). We will see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the reservation from the comments above that this isn't a good way to analyze the cohesiveness or conciseness of a text and that it will likely rather waste your time, you could use a text classification technique for preparing a word set for building a decision tree.

I don't know what this is called though.

We did this in an AI lab at UNI where we were tasked with classifying articles into one of two sets. (Someone defined them as "coal" and "cauliflower.")

You start by filtering out stopwords as you mention.

Then for each of the remaining words, you count how many documents it exists in. Let's call this value `N1` for the number of documents containing the word in set 1 and `N2` for the number of documents containing the word in set 2.

Finally, you determine the value of the word as:

```
ABS(N1 - N2)
```

This means that if the word exists in many documents in both sets, the number gets low. If it exists a lot in one set but not in the other the number gets high. If it doesn't exist a lot in either set the number gets low.

The number of documents in each set must be the same, or you should transform `N1` and `N2` into percentages of documents having the word in each set (i.e. divide `N1` with the total number of documents in set 1, etc).

When we compared the lists of words for each set we found "coal" was highly ranked in one set and "cauliflower" was highly ranked in the other. (And we took this list of words that was a good representation of the difference between the document sets and created a decision tree, but that's beside this discussion.)

I'm not sure how to do this for more than two sets of documents though, but the essence of the process would be to find words used a lot in one set and used much less in all the others.

Perhaps, for each set and each word do:

```
MAX(0, ABS(Nthis - N1 - N2 ... -Nx))
```

Where `Nthis` is the number of documents having the word in the current set. And `N1 - N2 - ... - Nx` is the number in the other documents. (Or percentages if the document sets are of different sizes.)

Or create an accumulative word score by calculating the score for the word in the current document set against all other document sets one at a time summing the word score.

You need to fire up your IDE and test approaches.

**Update: Pseudo code**

Not sure this helps but I couldn't stop myself... This would be how to calculate a word score for more than two sets... maybe...:

```
words       // all words in all document sets minus stop words
wordScore   // score of words
docSetWords // a list of doc sets that is a list of words in that doc set
            // i.e. docSetWords[0][0] = first word in first set (pseudowise...)

foreach word in words
  for i = 0 to docSetWords.length - 1
    for j = i + 1 to docSetWords.length
      N1 = count word in docSetWords[i]
      N2 = count word in docSetWords[j]
      wordScore[word] = wordScore[word] + ABS(N1 - N2)
      // I.e. sum of word scores
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://medium.com/nanonets/topic-modeling-with-lsa-psla-lda-and-lda2vec-555ff65b0b05, "topic modeling" might be the term, and "LSA" and "LDA" are useful techniques for that.

From that article (emphasis mine):

"In natural language understanding (NLU) tasks, there is a hierarchy of lenses through which we can extract meaning — from words to sentences to paragraphs to documents. At the document level, *one of the most useful ways to understand text is by analyzing its topics*. The process of learning, recognizing, and extracting these topics across a collection of documents is called **topic modeling**.

All topic models are based on the same basic assumption:

- each document consists of a mixture of topics, and
- each topic consists of a collection of words.
  In other words, topic models are built around the idea that the semantics of our document are actually being governed by some hidden, or “latent,” variables that we are not observing. As a result, *the goal of topic modeling is to uncover these latent variables* — topics — that shape the meaning of our document and corpus."

"**Latent Semantic Analysis**, or LSA, is one of the foundational techniques in topic modeling. The core idea is to take a matrix of what we have — documents and terms — and decompose it into a separate document-topic matrix and a topic-term matrix."

"LDA stands for **Latent Dirichlet Allocation**. [...] With LDA, we can extract human-interpretable topics from a document corpus, where each topic is characterized by the words they are most strongly associated with."

Comment: Before more downvoting, I'm not accepting my own answer (that I wrote after investigating this more thoroughly). The techniques mentioned do address my original question "I would expect to be able to get lists of words that are unique and telling for each topic," and it's called "topic modeling".